# Flex: How to change caret (text cursor) in editable text area / text input

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, textinput, caret

I need to put together an editable text area that has a custom caret (cursor) which is different from the default blinking vertical line.

Is the caret a "skinnable" property of text input?

Please note that I am not asking about the mouse pointer cursor which can be set using the CursorManager.

Thanks.
-Raj

Comment: hey have you ever got an answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

No, the look and behaviour of the caret is controlled by the Flash player itself. There is no programmatic access to it.