# Set mouse cursor as hand on textInput without losing text selection

Tags: apache-flex

I want to have the mouse cursor to be changed to hand when used for *entering* the `<mx:textInput>`. When the field is already on focus, text selection should be available.

I tried any combination of `useHandCursor="true"`, `buttonMode="true"` and `mouseChildren="false"`, and the closest result is when using all three of them. Then the hand cursor does appear, but the text field loses its selection 'abilities' (text cannot be selected using the mouse). This is logical, since `mouseChildren="false"` disables this. But how do I acheive the desired result?

P.S. using Flex 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<mx:TextInput id="textInput" mouseChildren="false" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" 
    focusIn="{textInput.mouseChildren = true}"
    focusOut="{textInput.mouseChildren = false}" />
```

But then when you select text the cursor will become a text selection icon.

Do you want that or do you want to have the icon a hand even when selecting text?

Comment: not necessarily. But if you have a thought on how to do it, share it :)

Comment: If it would be possible my guess is you need to skin the specific 'text select cursor' and then use the CursorManager class.

But I found a thread here says that this wouldn't be possible:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785535/flex-how-to-change-caret-text-cursor-in-editable-text-area-text-input